# How can I access the types in a C++ template parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I want to construct a class that represents a mapping from a value of type `I` to a value of type `O`.
I created this interface:

```
template <typename I, typename O> class Transform {
public:
    virtual O transform(I i) = 0;
};
```

Next, I want to allow `Transform` objects to be combined into a sort of "pipe lined" transformation:

```
template <typename X, typename Y, typename Z> class MergeTransform : public Transform<X, Z> {
private:
    Transform<X, Y> *first;
    Transform<Y, Z> *second;
public:
    MergeTransform(Transform<X, Y> *first, Transform<Y, Z> *second) {
        this->first = first;
        this->second = second;
    }
    Z transform(X x) {
        return second->transform(first->transform(x));
    }
};
```

What is stumping me at the moment is trying to figure out how to use a template to merge an arbitrary number of transformations. I wanted to do something like

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C> Transform<A, C> *merge(Transform<A, B> *t1, Transform<B, C> *t2) {
    return new MergeTransform(t1, t2);
}
template <typename A, typename... Bs, typename C> Transform<A, C> *merge(/* what should go here? */) {
    // ...
}
```

but then I'm at a loss at how to represent the list of `Transform`s from `A->B1, B1->B2, B2->...->Bn, Bn->C` in the second `merge` method.
I also considered letting the template parameters be the transforms themselves, ie.

```
/*
 * assume A and B are Transforms
 */
template <typename A, typename B> /* some return Transform type here */ *merge(A *a, B *b) {
    return new MergeTransform(a, b);
}
template <typename A, typename... Bs, typename C> /* return type */ *merge(A *a, Bs... bs, C *c) {
    return merge(merge(a, bs), c);
}
```

but cannot define the return type without knowing the templated types of the A and B `Transform`s. Is there a way to access these values? Ideally, I would be able to say

```
template <Transform<X, Y> A, Transform<Y, Z> B> Transform<X, Z> *merge(A *a, B *b) {
    return new MergeTransform(a, b);
}
template <Transform<W, X> A, Transform<?, ?>... Bs, Transform<Y, Z> C> Transform<W, Z> *merge(A *a, Bs... *bs, C *c) {
    return merge(merge(a, bs), c);
}
```

with the compiler throwing an error if the expansion of `merge(a, bs)` didn't return a `Transform<X, Y>`. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can use `auto` as return type since C++14.

Comment: You may want to consider looking into [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates), e.g. [used heavily in Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Expression_templates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With abuse of operator overloading and folding expression (C++17), you might do something like that to chain operation:

```
template <typename ... Fs>
class Chain
{
private: 
    template <typename F>
    struct CallerWrap
    {
        F f;
        CallerWrap(F f) : f(f) {}

        template <typename T>
        friend decltype(auto) operator+ (const CallerWrap& callerWrap, T&& x)
        {
            return callerWrap.f(std::forward<T>(x));
        }
    };

    std::tuple<Fs...> tup;  
public:

    Chain(Fs... fs) : tup{fs... }{}

    template <typename T>
    decltype(auto) operator()(T x) const {
        return std::apply([&x](auto... fs){ return (CallerWrap{fs} + ... + x); }, tup);
    }

};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eef86022cefd75b7)

There are no fold expressions for `f1(f2(f3(x)))` but there is for `f1 + (f2 + (f3 + x))` (and other binary operators).
So we add wrapper to use the later and be equivalent to the former.